# How generate multiple coin when dragging?

Tags: coronasdk

In my game.i have drag the coin to place some where.when i drag new coin has genate to replace that coin.plz help me.

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information for us to help you add the moment.  Please expand your question with code examples and what your current issue is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this will help.try collision event when old coin can colid to any other place generate the new coin.assign the value to newly created coin.